# mysql, how to make 'insert on duplicate key update' store prev. values?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

Why for table like this:

```
create table tbl (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    key1 int not null,
    key2 int not null,
    value0 double,
    value1 double,
    key(id),
    unique(key1,key2)
);
```

Following query is not storing prev. value of 'value0' to 'value1' when updating existing record? Is it possible at all?

```
insert into tbl (key1, key2, value0, value1) 
values (...), (...)
, ...
, (...) 
on duplicate key update value0=values(value0), value1=if(value0<>values(value0),value0, value1);
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? What do you mean by previous value? Maybe you need insert ingore, and not insert...on duplicate key  update?

Comment: Forgot to describe keys in create table statement, sorry. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Maybe you just need to switch your update statements: on duplicate key update value1=if(value0<>values(value0),value0, value1), value0=values(value0);

Comment: posted as answer along with explanation why this happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE updates the values sequentially (both in UPDATE and in DUPLICATE UPDATE statement).
This means that if you refer a value in your update statement, that was updated in the same statement, you'll get the updated value, and not the original one.

Because of this in the statement

```
on duplicate key update value0=values(value0), value1=if(value0<>values(value0),value0, value1);
```

value0 always equeals to values(value0) - it was updates in the previous part of the update statement. To make it work as you expect you have to switch the positions of the statements:

```
on duplicate key update value1=if(value0<>values(value0),value0, value1), value0=values(value0);
```